# Asp.net core mvc send array of int to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I do Ajax and then I have this piece of code (JavaScript):

```
document.getElementById("HidenLink").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("HidenLink").innerHTML = "I have found " + data.pocetfound + " cases";
var arrStr = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data.listfound));
var Path = " ";
switch ('@ViewBag.TableName') {
         case "MYCASE":
              Path = "PATJ/PATHH"
         break;
       }
document.getElementById("HidenLink").href = Path + '/IDArr?array=' + arrStr;
```

Then I expect to get int[] IDArr in my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MYRIGHTPATH(int? id, int[] IDArr)
{
  try {
    /*TESTS*/
     foreach (int i in IDArr) //Does not get executed
      {
         Console.WriteLine(i);
      }
        /*TESTS*/
   }catch (Exception e) {
                return RedirectToAction("Error", new { error = e });
            }
        }
```

My endpoint:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

My problem is that controller does not get array I am trying to send.

Thanks for help!

Comment: change `, int[] IDArr` to `string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> expect to get int[] IDArr in my Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MYRIGHTPATH(int? id, int[] IDArr)`
```

To achieve your requirement, you can pass the data through query string like below.

```
?IDArr=1&IDArr=2
```

Or

```
?IDArr[0]=1&IDArr[1]=2
```

Test Result

[image]

For more information about model binding, please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections